# multiple selection in metabase filter

Tags: metabase

The question is related to metabase
I'm creating a new sql question
I add a filter to it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xquNY.png)

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable (nolock)
[[WHERE category = {{category}}]]
```

Next, I add this request to the dashboard and want to apply a multiple choice filter to it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCm11.png)

But I get the following error:
"This field only accepts a single value because it's used in a SQL query."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65KlO.png)

I tried changing the filter type for the request, but it didn't work

I need a multiple filter per request